# Select all fields plus some new fields in LINQ VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I want to convert simple SQL to LINQ (**only VB.Net solution please**)

SQL: SELECT *, 'value' as col1 FROM TableA

LINQ: ?

I already try this:

```
Dim query = From c In dbContext.TableAs _
            Select c, col1 = "value"

e.QueryableSource = query

or:  Select New With {c, .col1 = "value"}

or:  Let col1 = "value"
     Select c, col1
```

Nothing's works.  Thanks in advance.

Added.
This code works:

```
Dim dbContext As New TestLINQDataContext
Dim query = From c In dbContext.TableAs _
                Where c.colA > 10 _
                Select c.colA, c.colB, c.colC, col1 = "value"

e.KeyExpression = "colA"
e.QueryableSource = query
```

The problem is that I have more tables with 30 and more columns, so I don’t want to write columns in Select one by one but I want to use * for all columns plus one extra with my calculated value.

Comment: clarify if the "query" has the correct values? if so, share its state...

Comment: Anyone? I still need the answer.